# EditText not scrolling horizontally

Tags: android, android-edittext, horizontal-scrolling

I have created an EditText using:

```
    <style name="foredits">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
    </style>
```

When creating the EditText,I put in a layout_weight,an id and a id as other attributes.I would like the EditText to scroll horizontally when:

a.hint does not fit within the bounds of the edittext 
b.text is being entered and the text goes past the right edge of the edittext's bounds

Because,this has not been scrolling horizontally,I have also tried with a ScrollingMovementMethod

```
   edit_mul.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
   edit_mul.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This does not seem to work either.How do I get this working?

Comment: can i show your xml code ?

Comment: definetely,i just need to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good i did the following for vertical Scroll Bar
xml
    `<TextView
                android:id="@+id/response_sms_textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="8"
                android:maxLines="8"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- include -->
                android:text="@string/without_account_response_sms_tv3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />`

code
    tv3.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); // include

but if you put this inside ScrollView layout might not work. Thanks

Comment: i am looking for horizontal scrolling now,but i will refer to your answer when implementing vertical scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following parameters in the edittext.

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setClickable(false);
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
edittext.setEnabled(true);
edittext.setKeyListener(null);
edittext.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

So it will work as the desired behaviour.